# Cucumber extent report- getting error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: cucumber

I am working with cucumber - extent report flow: getting error on using com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter: Please help me out

when ran as JUnit: getting following Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The plugin specification 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:' has a problem:

Could not load plugin class 'com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter'.
```